# Can't sudo unmount or remove a temp folder in macOS catalina, how to get rid of it?

Tags: macos, sudo, removable-media, unmount, unmounting

Using macOS Catalina 10.15.6. I have a folder `~/temp/foobar` and when I do `ls -al` it shows these file flags:

> drwx------

For some reason I cannot get rid of the folder. So far I have tried this:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /Users/rocketnuts/temp/foobar
rm: /Users/rocketnuts/temp/foobar: Device not configured

$ sudo umount /Users/rocketnuts/temp/foobar
umount(/Users/rocketnuts/temp/foobar): Resource busy -- try 'diskutil unmount'

$ sudo diskutil unmount /Users/rocketnuts/temp/foobar
Unmount failed for /Users/rocketnuts/temp/foobar
```

Note that this folder is actually a leftover from a previous `sshfs` mount. But it got disconnected and the sshfs session is already killed. After doing `pkill -kill -f "sshfs"` the above commands still give the same results.

When I do `lsof /Users/rocketnuts/temp/foobar` (or with `sudo`) it shows no usage by any process.

How do I get rid of this?

Comment: Did you try `umount` with the -f option?

Comment: I'm not an expert in `lsof`, but searching around for this exact issue, others recommended doing `lsof -n | grep foobar` to find any process using using your sshfs mount.  Not sure if only using the folder name (not the path) will help, but worth trying.